# Injecting or Inheriting Router Builder for global onException in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, onexception

I have `onException` configured in one `DefaultRouteBuilder` class. I want this `onException` in all other routes in my context. My doubt is whether I should inherit `DefaultRouteBuilder` in all other routes and calling `super.configure()` in `configure()` method or to inject `DefaultRouteBuilder defaultRoute` in all other `RouteBuilder` classes and calling `defaultRoute.configure()` in `configure()` method. Which one should be appropriate?

Comment: I would go with `super.configure()` - since you have no further need for a RouteBuilder once the route has been configured, using inheritance would be fine.

Comment: @vikingsteve I am sure both of them will work fine. I dont see any reason why I would not choose Injecting a defaultRouteBuilder in all other routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global onException DSL only work inside of same RouteBuilder, as camelcontext treat the routebuilder instance separately.

Comment: are you telling that Injecting defaultRouteBuilder would cause issues as there are technically no routes defined in that RouteBuilder. Calling defaultRouteBuilder.configure() would not actually hook onException for routes in the ActualRouteBuilder where I inject the defaultRouteBuilder. Am I right ?

Comment: I would have looked at the onException implementation before asking this Question. Thanks